# c# even number and factorial

Tags: c#, numbers, factorial

So I have problem... I need to build program with C# windows form, and calculate with texbox1 and textbox2 factorials and show even numbers in richtextbox, and use FOR cycle, I have builded this solution but it gives me only one number.....It is mind****.... If you know what I mean...
Any sugestions?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        int fact = 1;
        for (int i = x; i<=y; i++)
        {
            fact = fact * y;
        }
        richTextBox1.Text = fact.ToString();
    }
```

Well In mind I have build this one too, what do you think about it? 
And maby someone can tell me how to use it?

```
for (int i = X; i <= Y; i++)
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        fakt = 1;

        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--)
            fakt = fakt * j;
    }
```

Comment: you're overiding `fact` in every iteration you're doing so there will be everytime only one result

Comment: Damn..you are right...My foult, but it only calculates as I think those numbers...And gives me only one line

Comment: What output are you expecting?  Also you are not calculating factorials here

Comment: factorials are `1 * 2 * 3 * ... * n`. You're not doing that, you're doing `x * (x+1) * (x+2) * ... * (y)`, and this would only ever work if `x > y`

Comment: I'm expecting output like this
X = 1;  Y = 5;

=========================

|  Number       |    Factorial
=========================

|         2           |             2            |

|         4           |            24           |

=========================

Comment: Ahh... so this is why my program doesn't work... :D

Comment: do `richTextBox1.Text += fact.ToString() + "|" ;` inside your `for` loop, to get started

Comment: Which cycle is better FOR or WHILE?

Comment: FOR is better for what you are currently doing.

Comment: i dont understand the j loop at all

Comment: When I am using it in CMD C# it calculates all great, and gives me what I want, but windows form doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by defining our factorial function. You said it **had to be** a *for loop*, so:

```
private int Factorial(int n) {
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        result *= i;
    return result;
}
```

Now, you said you wanted the textbox to have the format:

```
X = 1; Y = 4;
=======================|Number|Factorial|====================
=======================|2|2|=================================
=======================|4|24|================================
```

Let's start by making a function that will print the column headers:

```
private void PrintHeaders(int x, int y) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.AppendFormat("X = {0}; Y = {1}", x, y);
    builder.AppendLine();
    builder.AppendLine("===============|Number|Factorial|=============");
    richTextBox1.Text = builder.ToString();
}
```

And, lastly, our *click event handler*:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    int y = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    PrintHeaders(x, y);
    for(int i = x; i <= y; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
           int result = Factorial(i);   
           richTextBox1.Text += "==========|" + i + "|" + result + "|=============";
           richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dam.....You are good at this!!! Thanks for the help, need to study this code right now THANKS !!!!!

Comment: I made it on the fly, so if you encounter any problems just tell me :)

Comment: Heh...one thing we have forgoten, that thing is to calculate only in interval from texbox1 (x) to textbox2 (y), not all numbers to break program :D :D :D

Comment: @itboxpaslaugos My bad :). Modified last `for loop`, I was doing `x++`. Changed it to `i++`

Comment: @itboxpaslaugos Another mistake of mine. You should change `Factorial(x)` to `Factorial(i)`, in the last `for loop`

Comment: And found another mistake, but it's normal ;))), Now when I have changed factorial to i it gives us
X = 2; Y = 10
|2|2|
|2|6| and etc....

Comment: And still there is one more problem......that it still now calculates 1 2 3 4 5.... when i enter (X)2 (Y)10
We need even numbers only, to calculate

Comment: Ok, added an **even** check at the beginning of the last `for loop`. That should solve it :)

Comment: Hey guys have one more question, maby you know and can help, how to make align, for this program with those | center and | right?